# obfuscates android source by ProGuard(All Activity)

Tags: java, android, obfuscation

I want to obfuscate all my Android App's activities by using **ProGuard** but my ProGuard configuration is not working.

Some of the source code  is being obfuscated but still showing my source on reverse engineering.

My proguard.cfg below:

```
-overloadaggressively
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-microedition
-printseeds
```

I want to obfuscate all code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this config

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

Also you can build this config alternatively in gradle file as

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
```

You can also check out the samples from your sdk ie sdk/tools/proguard

Answer (score 0):

```
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated, SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
# -dontpreverify
# Optimization settings

# Keep (ie. don't remove) all public constructors of all public classes, but still obfuscate+optimize their content. This is necessary because optimization removes constructors which I use through reflection.

-optimizations field/*,!class/*,!method/*
```